# Android: Are locally-stored encryption keys readable by attacker who gained root access?

Tags: encryption, android

i have a question:

i'm trying to understand a specific point in android encryption.

All the encryption keys are software based and are stored locally on the machine, so correct me if i'm wrong but doesn't it mean that attacks on android phones where the attacker gains root access means that the attacker can retrieve the encryption keys?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if an attacker has root on the machine they will be able to read all secrets stored on the device.  root can attach a debugger to any process and observe memory or hook function calls.

A mobile app should not attempt to hide secrets from the user, and server-side functionality should not trust mobile clients.  These are common mobile vulnerabilities.    Some apps attempt to detect root'ed devices,  but this can always be bypassed.